# Data Labelling in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have actually written code which allows a user to query out the data from five fields and plot a scatter graph using two of the five fields. If I click on some random data point, I want it to display all the corresponding five fields of data. Is this possible?

<sub>P.S. I am not able to upload any pics because I am new here.</sub>

Comment: Post the image and I will fix your post so that it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I have code for a chart that displays a text box with details of the series when I click on it. I can provide the basics and you can try and play aorund with it.

Note: This works when you have a chart sheet with the code sitting in behind it. Not sure how it would go with multiple charts on an excel sheet.

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

Dim ElementID as Long, Arg1 as Long, Arg2 as Long

Me.GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

If ElementID = xlSeries Then 'Making sure that a series was selected

'Do some code here, using any or all of the variables gathered in the Me.GetChartElement

Else

End If

End Sub
```